# vue3, route.push is not a function. I can't find the soluction of this error in google

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I create apps with vue3 and laravel.
When I submit text in textbox, addCategory function fires.
at this time, I want to redirect the default page.
But route.push causes below error.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: route.push is not a function

[image]

This is my code.

```
<script setup>

import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()


const addCategory = async () => {

    await submitNewCategory()
    await getCategories()
    newCategory.value = ''
    // route.push({name: 'category.show', params: {categoryId: categoryId + 1 }})
    route.push('/')
}
</script>

<template>
        <div class="form-box">
            <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 10px">RECIPE HOUSE</h4>
            <form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="addCategory">
                <input type="text" v-model="newCategory">
            </form>
        </div>
</template>
```

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import CategoryHome from './components/CategoryHome.vue'
import CategoryShow from './components/CategoryShow.vue'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'category.home',
        components: {
            Home: CategoryHome
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/categories/:categoryId',
        name: 'category.show',
        components: {
            Show: CategoryShow
        },
        props: true
    },
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})

const app = createApp({})
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

Is there some kind of a problem other than router.push?
Thank you for your help.
I'm sorry that My English isn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `router=useRouter()` and `route=useRoute()` are 2 different objects.
The `router` is the router instance you make with `createRouter` that handles all the routing. `route` is the current route instance.

What you want to do is push a route to the router, not the route object (which btw doesn't have a method called push which in turn gives your error),

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter()


const addCategory = async () => {
    if (categories.value.length === 0)
    {
        noData.value = !noData.value
    }
    await submitNewCategory()
    await getCategories()
    newCategory.value = ''
    // router.push({name: 'category.show', params: {categoryId: categoryId + 1 }})
    router.push('/')
}
```

Comment: Rereading my question now, This was not clear enough. English grammar was also strange. I understood what you say and the error fixes. Thank you for giving me a hand！